# jProfiler - need to deploy linux agent via UCD

Tags: deployment, download, agent, jprofiler

I need to deploy the agent using puppet or UCD.
We are using jProfiler Version 11.0.1.
I've tried to get the download path for that version, but all I can get via Documentation is the version for jProfiler 12.0.
Is there any way to get the download link for older versions of jDownloader Agent?

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler 11.1 can be downloaded at:

https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/version_111

Agent-only downloads are only available starting with JProfiler 12. In previous versions you can use the remote integration wizard (Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration) to create archives that only contain the agent files.